# CAS - use different authentication handlers based on user input of their username

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

Is it possible to use different authentication methods based on user input of their username?

If the username begins with a digit, use JDBC authentication.

If the username begins with a letter, use LDAP.

I am kind of confused reading the documentation. Please give me some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Always ensure you have enough diagnostics data in your report, the exact CAS version numbers and other details.

According to the documentation,

> Most authentication strategies in CAS are given a predicate to examine the requested credential for eligibility. This predicate is simply a fancy a condition whose outcome determines whether the authentication strategy/handler should proceed to operate on the credential.

```
...
cas.authn.jdbc.search[0].credential-criteria=.+@tenantA\.org
...
cas.authn.ldap[0].credential-criteria=.+@tenantB\.org
...
```

See [this link](https://fawnoos.com/2017/10/23/cas-multitenancy) for details and notes.

Comment: Thanks. When I add `cas.authn.rest.credential-criteria=.+@example\.org`, the console warns: `Failed to bind properties under 'cas' to org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties .... Listed settings above are no longer recognized by CAS 6.3.0-SNAPSHOT. They may have been renamed, removed, or relocated to a new namespace in the CAS configuration schema.` Is it renamed to something else for `rest`?